# Начало работы строки только по завершению предыдущей

Tags: jquery

Вот, предположим, есть код. Проблема в том, что 2-я строчка уже начнет выполнение, пока у первой еще идет slideDown(1000).

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы вторая начала работу только тогда, когда первая уже закончит?

```
$("<p id='label_text'>best.ru</p>").prependTo($("#label_wrapper")).hide().slideDown(1000);
 $("<div id='gradient'></div>").prependTo($("#line_label")).hide().slideDown(1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("<p id='label_text'>best.ru</p>").prependTo($("#label_wrapper")).hide().slideDown(1000, function(){
    $("<div id='gradient'></div>").prependTo($("#line_label")).hide().slideDown(1000);
});
```